# The deployment failed because no instances were found in your green fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codedeploy

I have created a blue-green deployment in AWS CodeDeploy with the option Manually provision instances.

but when I run pipeline code deploy show error `The deployment failed because no instances were found in your green fleet.

So how to define green and blue feet? or what I miss?
`

[image]